# Custom naming for JSON properties - JAX-RS unmarshalling

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs, pojo

I'm having a JAX-RS web application method which takes a JSON entity and produces one. But I'm having problems with the POJOS matching the consumed JSON entity, specificly with their annotations.

How do I configure the POJOS so I don't need to write the name of the properties in the consumed JSON entity? I would rather have a custom name for them.

**Example**

Prefered JSON entity:

```
{
"foo_bar" : "spam"
}
```

POJO:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A {

    private String fooBar;

    public String getFooBar() {
        return fooBar;

    public void setFooBar(String fooBar) {
        this.fooBar = fooBar;
}
```

So far I tried the @XmlElement(name="foo_bar") annotation, but it didn't work. Some other stackoverflow thread suggested @JsonProperty("foo_bar"), but what's the difference between them? Additionally, does this annotation work with the existing @Xml annotations?

Comment: If you want to generate/consume XML you use the `@XML` tags, if you want to generate/consume JSON you use the `@Json` tags.

Comment: Where exactly did you put this annotation @JsonProperty("foo_bar") ? The code doesn't show what all things you have tried exactly.

Comment: I have not tested the JsonProperty annotation yet, because I wanted to know if this will work together with the other annotations. I'm a bit confused about the different ways to bind entities... you have JAXB for XML-binding, Jackson for JSON-binding, etc. Am I allowed to just mix the different binding annotations up in my POJOs? Another thing which is unclear to me is, what's the difference between Json and JsonB annotations? Soz, if I'm a bit chaotic...